# How to deal with a long-running database query in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, web-applications

I was a windows desktop application programmer, and I am new to ASP.NET.

When I execute a long-running database query at Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e), users have to wait until the query is done (the query takes a long time).

Can I use SqlDataReader to pull data from a table row-by-row in another thread and send the data to users row-by-row? In this way, the users doesn't need to wait until the all rows are pulled from the database.

If I write a windows desktop application with the WPF framework, I can pull data from the database row-by-row in another thread and use BeginInvoke pattern to send the data to UI row-by-row.

However, when I write a web application with ASP.NET, I don't know what is the best way to do it. Can I pull data row-by-row in another thread and put the pulled data to Session, then I send a XMLHttpRequest periodically to get the pulled data from Session?

I am wondering if there is a long-running database query, what is the best practice for dealing with it in ASP.NET?

Comment: Best practice - don't have a long running query. Rethink the way page interacts with the SP. E.g. If it produces large dataset, implement a paging mechanism when only small portion of data is displayed to the user at a time.

Comment: If the resulting data is not too dynamic (not changing based on user), you could look at [ASP.NET output caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.ASPX)

Comment: Long running queries should not be invoked on page_load.If the process is going to take time and you need the application to be responsive, you have to revisit your query and either try to optimize it or make an async Ajax call once the page has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use SqlDataReader to pull data from a table row-by-row in
>   another thread and send the data to users row-by-row? In this way, the
>   users doesn't need to wait until the all rows are pulled from the
>   database.

The problem is ASP.NET applications have a different life-cycle than Windows Form applications. Once you render the page and send a response to the user, you can no longer work with the data. What you *can* do is use javascript. You can use an UpdatePanel, ASP.NET's implementation of AJAX, or work with XMLHttpRequests. (JQuery, I'm sure you've heard, simplifies these requests using $.ajax). You could have a loading .gif in place of your data, and have javascript fetch the data after the page is ready.

Row-by-row loading may be trickier. The code below will start a database call, and return the rendered page before the query has finished:

```
    protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM db.Tablename;"
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback (BuildDataSet), query);

    }

    private void BuildDataSet(object query)
    {
        Queue Q = new Queue();

        //Connection String, etc.

        while rdr.Read()
        {
            Q.Enqueue(rdr["Column"];
        }
    }
```

You would need a second page to handle your XMLHttpRequests fetching the rows. The difficulty will be in persisting this data, identifying it between requests, and possibly memory management.

The easiest path I can think of is to do a `SELECT TOP (50)` on page_load, and then ajax in the full data once it has been fetched.